# Windows Azure and web.config doesn't run with PHP web site

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess, codeigniter, azure

I've got to create a small application  with CodeIgniter, and I try to use the web site module from Windows Azure.

I converted my .htaccess from this [link](http://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx).
My .htaccess look like at this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The result look like at this:

```
<rule name="rule 1y" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}"  />
</rule>
```

But, when I go in my web site, I've got this error:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following lines to your web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

PS: Do not repeat system.webServer and system.web sections in your web.config. Add the configurations to the existing one.