# Kudu Debug Console access denied error when trying to save edits

Tags: azure, iis

I'm getting the following message when trying to save edits to rootweb.config:

> Could not write to local resource 'D:\local\Config\rootweb.config' due
>   to error 'Access to the path 'D:\local\Config\rootweb.config' is
>   denied.'.

I'm trying to add the following to the file's default configuration after uploading my PHP project (my PHP project didn't include a web.config file):

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="<ip-address>" />
            <!--add allowed="true" ipAddress="<ip-address>" /-->                        
        </ipSecurity>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Is this file supposed to be editable, or do I need to include my own web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on another Stack Overflow post I believe you just want to make a web.config and put it in the folder of your php app. You can not edit the configs in that folder you tried to access. You can modify the applicationHost.config via a site extension with a transform. I have experience doing that.

[Windows Azure and web.config doesn't run with PHP web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180744/windows-azure-and-web-config-doesnt-run-with-php-web-site)

About Site extensions:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Site-Extensions